# Oracle - NO_DATA_FOUND error, but there is data

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, cursor

I have a PL/SQL block that I put into a stored procedure so that I can debug it. Here is a bit of pseudocode to describe the PL/SQL block:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SPROC_A AS

  CURSOR CURSOR_A IS
    SELECT ID, YEAR
      FROM TABLE_A;

  vNAME VARCHAR2(200) := NULL;

BEGIN
  FOR REC IN CURSOR_A LOOP

    BEGIN
      SELECT NVL(B.FIELD_1, B.FIELD_2) INTO vNAME  --the sproc breaks here--
        FROM TABLE_B B
       WHERE B.ID = REC.ID       
         AND B.YEAR = REC.YEAR
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        vNAME := NULL;
    END;

    UPDATE TABLE_C C
       SET C.NAME = vNAME
     WHERE C.ID = REC.ID       
       AND C.YEAR = REC.YEAR;

  END LOOP;
END;
```

If I run this portion independently and supply my own values for REC.ID and REC.YEAR, data is returned:

```
SELECT NVL(B.FIELD_1, B.FIELD_2) --INTO vNAME
  FROM TABLE_B B
 WHERE B.ID = REC.ID         
   AND B.YEAR = REC.YEAR
```

Furthermore, the variable into which I am trying to select data is of datatype VARCHAR2(200) - TABLE_B.FIELD_1 and TABLE_B.FIELD_2 are both of datatype VARCHAR2(40), so there shouldn't be a mismatch of datatypes.

What else could I be missing here?

Comment: Assuming you don't just have uncommitted data, is data returned when you run that query manually for *every* pair of values from table A, or did you just try one set? Have you debugged to see what the REC values are immediately before it fails? (You're squashing the exception so not quite sure how you know what's going on...). Presumably your real code is more complicated - otherwise why not join in the cursor query, or just do a single correlated update instead of looping at all?

Comment: What would be a better way of handling the exception?

Comment: It may be appropriate to default to null like that if there is no matching data in B, but the only way you can tell that's happening is if you can see that you updated a row in table_c to null - and even then that assumes table_b.field_2 cannot be null. You said the procedure 'breaks' at that select, but as you're catching no_data_found that won't 'break' it in an obvious way?

Comment: table_b.field_2 can be null and in this case, I have realized that the field in table_c is not actually being updated to null.

Comment: It can't fail with `no_data_found` at the line indicated, because you explicitly handle that exception. However `select id, year from table_a minus select id, year from table_b` would list the key values that exist in A but not B.